# Question on quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Graph of two quadratic expressions $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ are shown in image, where $f(x) = x^2+2ax+b$ and $g(x) = cx^2+2dx+1$, 
(where $a$ $b$ $c$ $d$ are real)

Given that $|OB'| = 2|OA'|$ and $|BB'| = 2|AA'|$

If $|AA'| = 1$ and the equation $k^2(g(x))^2+(k-1)g(x)+2=0$ has exactly two real and distinct roots then the set of all possible values of k is.

[image: graphs of f(x) and g(x)]

I really don't have any idea on how should I proceed to solve this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that an accurate representation of $f(x)$? Does it go through the origin like that? Or is that just an artifact of your sketch?

Comment: It does not go through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**
1. If $|AA'|=1$ then the $y$-coordinate of the vertex of $f(x)$ is $-1$.
 
2. Complete the square on $f(x)$ and you will find the $x$-coordinate of the vertex is $-a$ and $b=(-a^2-1)$.
3. Clearly $c<0$.
4. Complete the square on $g(x)$ to find $\frac{d}{c}$, which should be twice $a$, given $|OB'| = 2|OA'|$.

Now you should have an idea what $c$ and $d$ are, so $k$ is your only variable. If that last equation has two real roots, it crosses the $x$-axis twice. Find the values of $k$ where this doesn't happen, and you have your range of answers.

Comment: Shouldn't the x coordinate be -a

Comment: @Gem you're right. Editing the answer.

Comment: b will also change accordingly